# JQassistant rule for TestMethods with lambda expressions and consumers asserts

Tags: neo4j, java-8, cypher, consumer, jqassistant

Our project has few Unit Tests in which the asserts are passed as a lambda or consumer to the test class. Example as below. **How to write a cypher rule constraint** such the asserts are identified and the method is not flagged as without assert. Currently using junit4:TestMethodWithoutAssertion

Test Method :

```
     @Test 
     public void testSuccessfulIdempotency(){
     transportConsumerFlow.accept(Mockito.mock(TransRequest.class), 
     (t)->{
           assertEquals(t, expectedResponseMessage);
      });
     }
```

In the sample above, the assert is actually present and valid. But the concept junit4:AssertMethod could not detected may be because it is present as a consumer instead of a direct invocation in Test method.

Comment: @Dirk Mahler : Is it that JQassistant doesn't support lambda constructs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda expressions are currently not explicitly support by jQAssistant but you may identify them as synthetic static methods (as generated by the bytecode) using the following concept:

```
MATCH
  (type:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(lambda:Method)
WHERE
  exists(lambda.synthetic)
  and exists(lambda.static)
  and lambda.name starts with("lambda$")
SET
  lambda:Lambda
WITH
  type, lambda
MATCH
  (type)-[:DECLARES]->(method:Method)
WHERE
  method <> lambda
  and method.firstLineNumber <= lambda.firstLineNumber
  and method.lastLineNumber >= lambda.lastLineNumber
MERGE
  (method)-[:DECLARES_LAMBDA]->(lambda)
RETURN
  method, collect(lambda)
```

You'll not see any INVOKES relations from the test methods to the lambda methods, so a custom constraint with the following cypher query needs to be used (based on junit4:TestMethodWithoutAssertion):

```
MATCH
  (testType:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(testMethod:Test:Method)
WHERE
  NOT (testMethod)-[:INVOKES|DECLARES_LAMBDA*..3]->(:Method:Assert)
RETURN
  testType AS DeclaringType,
  testMethod AS Method
```

Comment: :Thanks for response! However, the clause 
and method.firstLineNumber <= lambda.firstLineNumber
  and method.lastLineNumber >= lambda.lastLineNumber doesn't seem to work. Seems that firstLineNumber,lastLineNumber attributes are not available.

Comment: Just tried it with the following test class and it worked:

    public class LambdaTest {
    
        @Test
        public void lambda() {
            Stream.of("1", "2").forEach(s -> assertThat(s, notNullValue()));
        }
    }

Have you verified if you can execute the query in the Neo4j browser by starting the server (mvn jqassistant:server) and if it returns results?

Comment: I just executed the above given concept in the Neo4j browser and it didn't give any result."no - rows found". Any pre-requisites ? minimum version ?

Comment: After upgrading to jqassistant version 1.3.0 and maven compiler to enforce 1.8 Java version, this approach worked ! Thanks much !

Comment: One correction in the above concept. Instead of 
         RETURN
           method, collect(lambda)
It could be Just 
        RETURN
          method

Comment: I've just created a sample branch "jqa-lambda" in the demo application (https://github.com/buschmais/spring-petclinic/), just have a look at jqassistant/java8.adoc and jqassistant/test.adoc. A test class LambdaTest provides provides two test methods (with/without assertion), the later is reported by jQA.